# how to change properties of html elements in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an element which is automatically generated via my API call as

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.work.com/reward"><b class="orange tdu">My Work History</b></a>
```

now i want to modify it like

```
<a ng-click="message(messageItem.id)">
```

i.e I want to remove the original properties and add angulars ng-click to it.

**I cannot use JQuery.**

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Comment: nothing in particular......but i am thinking of selecting that element via document.getElementById and change that property...but i don't know how to do that

Comment: Just adding the property wont work - you need to recompile the HTML against the `$scope` to get the `ngClick` recognized.

Comment: Why you donnot use `window.location` in your javascript function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this in your controller.

1: select the element and remove unwanted attributes using

`element.removeAttribute("target"`);

2: Add required attribute on the element using

```
element.setAttribute('ng-click', 'loadMicrosite(messageItem.id)'); '' you can use string concatenation for messageItem.id
```

3: Now you have the updated element in the DOM but its not attached with the scope yet. Use $compile for it. As per  angular docs $compile

Compiles an HTML string or DOM into a template and produces a template function, which can then be used to link scope and the template together.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope,$compile) {
  
var sNew = document.querySelector('a');
sNew.removeAttribute("target");
sNew.removeAttribute("href");
sNew.setAttribute('ng-click', 'loadMicrosite(messageItem.id)');


$compile(sNew)($scope);
  
 $scope.loadMicrosite = function(param)
 {
   alert("I am called");
 }
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
   <a target="_blank" href="http://sprintweb.abc.com/sos-children-s-villages-of-india-new-delhi-delhi"><b class="orange tdu">SOS Children's Villages of India</b></a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: Sure @MikeMcCaughan Update the answer with details.

Comment: can u also tell me what should i do if i have multiple `<a>` elements.........do i loop over each one and perform the same thing for every one else.

Comment: you can do that but first check why do you need such implementation, if possible just take the link text from auto generation part and create new element using that.

Comment: isn't this what  you have done in the example.......remove the attribute and then add new

Comment: Yupp thats the way to solve a single issue but if there are many then it become a  design problem thats why suggested to look the other face of the coin.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your html from api and open the page with `window.open`

In html:

```
<a ng-click="loadMicrosite(messageItem.id)">
   <b class="orange tdu">SOS Children's Villages of India</b>
</a>
```

In Controller:

```
$scope.loadMicrosite = (id) ->
  url = getStringOfUrlFromServer
  window.open(
  url,
  '_blank');
```